# Store bearerToken until expires

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application that consumes a REST service from another server, which has its own authentication method to be able to consume its services.

Today, for each request we have, I am calling the authentication service then i receivethe bearerToken (which has a duration of 3 hours) and after that I call the endpoint I want to use.

The flow works without problems but I would like to know if there is a way to store this token in the same application and thus request the renewal of this only when it has expired, avoiding to call the authentication in each request.

Comment: Yes, you can. For example, in application cache.

Comment: @PM77-1 you mean something like this? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: You can do what Spring does: do the request, if you get an "unauthorized", get a new token and repeat the first request with the new token.

Comment: @vanOekel sure, but how can I store that token? is there any dependency that does that?

Comment: Use a Bean that has a `volatile` variable that holds the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the Caffeine Cache library to store the token. Here is the tutorial I followed in case anyone needs it

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-caffeine-cache

Answer (score 0):

Store both the token and the expiry time in the application. Whenever you need to use the token, check the expiry time. If need be renew the token before using it.

Comment: Sure, I understand that point, but how or where can I save these values?